# Error when login in Facebook Mobile

Tags: facebook, qt, authentication, qml

I have a problem when I try to login to facebook mobile.

I develop program on mobile with Qt QML.

At first, I use this code for a while and it worked fine. But a few days ago, it stopped working as usual.

So, I tried to write a very simple code sample, just for testing, and it gave me a same error.

This is my simple code:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import QtWebKit 1.0

Rectangle {
  width: 360
  height: 640

  WebView {
    id: web
    //anchors.fill: parent
    preferredHeight: 640
    preferredWidth: 360
    url: "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.gimme5.co.cc/login_success.html&response_type=token&display=touch"
  }

}
```

*I already replace the app id when I run it.*

It gave me an error in a pink square like this:

```
This page contains the following errors
error on line 2 at column 212 : Expected ';' but got '='
Below is a rendering of the page up to
```

So, what should I do?

Comment: I've just tried this with my own app id and it works fine for me.

The only piece of information you haven't included is your app_id. Just to sanity check that, it's a long number, right? No semi colons or anything in it?

Comment: @mrtom 

it didn't work... 

also my friend who develop app about fb on nokia too.

I feel really hopeless. I have 5 more days before deadline

it used to work fine!

:'(

btw, thank you for your response :)

Comment: Can I suggest you try and get it working not on the QT platform. Then you can at least figure out if this is a problem at the FB side or the QT side.

Comment: @mttom, thank you for your suggestion. Actually it works fine when I run it on an emulator. But got an error when I run it on device (nokia C7 & N8) So i really don't know what should I do :(

Comment: In that case I'm going to suggest this is a qt specific problem and not related to Facebook. Unfortunately I don't know anything about qt :(

Comment: @mrtom I can fix it now. I just change the url from "www.facebook.com" to "touch.facebook.com" and it works fine! btw, thank you so much that you come here and try to help me in may ways. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

changing from www.facebook.com to touch.facebook.com as a comment suggested didn't help for me.

however changing &display=touch to &display=wap does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Changing display property to wap really does the trick but page doesn't look nice then. Try to fake the user agent that is sent with your request. Check the `QString QWebPage::userAgentForUrl(const QUrl & url)` function. [Link to documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#userAgentForUrl). Look which user agent is sent when your request is made from simulator.